# Initializing all elements of a global array to the same non-zero value

Tags: c

I am trying to find a way to initialize all the elements of a global array of unknown fixed size to a non-zero value (0xffffffff).

If *array* were of fixed known size, this would not be problem, as I could brute force the initialization of each element to 0xffffffff as with the following:

```
static unsigned int array [4] = {0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff};
```

Unfortunately, I am dealing with an array of unknown fixed size.  In the example below, **SOME_CFG_OPTION** is defined at build time.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE   ROUND_UP(SOME_CFG_OPTION);

static unsigned int array [ARRAY_SIZE];  /* array in BSS and elements init'd to 0 */
```

One obvious answer is to initialize *array* in a constructor or a function that is called very early.  In our setup, this is not an option as it has too high an impact on our boot time.

The following worked well for us when we build with either the GNU or Intel C compilers.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE   ROUND_UP(SOME_CFG_OPTION);

static unsigned int array [ARRAY_SIZE]
                    = { [0 ... (ARRAY_SIZE- 1)] = 0xffffffff };
```

However, when we try this with the DIAB C compiler (which we must also support), it barfs on that approach, with the following error

```
line #: error (etoa:4029): expected an expression
            = { [0 ... (ARRAY_SIZE - 1)] = 0xffffffff };
                   ^
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this when compiling with the DIAB C Compiler?

Comment: Using memset() would require calling it very early in the code, which is not an option in our setup.

Comment: Why not use `std::array`?

Comment: @ZacHowland: A C compiler wouldn't take kindly to that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah, the C++ tag has been removed.

Comment: Use code generation during the build to produce the array initialization statement.

Comment: @SergeyL. The size can be any multiple of 32 between 32 and 256 inclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diab's syntax analyzer don't parse "..." very well. I ran into this about a year ago and the only solution I found was using memset.

The way I did it was to memset everything to 0. I then defined a macro:

```
#define USE_MEM(x) ~x;
```

I was dealing with bit manipulation so this works fine. I would not do this in bootcode though as inverse have big impact. In case of that, it's probably less expensive to figure out where the data is first used and apply initial value manually, e.g. add mem = 0xffffffff right before the value first being used.

I was using diab 5.2.1.0